# Unexpected token "end of template" of value "" ("end of statement block" expected)

Tags: templating, javascript

Good afternoon,

I'm new in Craft so I installed this step-by-step and I tried to install this theme: https://github.com/duezerouno/0-201

After I did everything, I can see a template error on my site that shows the next: *Unexpected token "end of template" of value "" ("end of statement block" expected).*

Looks like the error is on the **_head.twig** file and says that:

```
<head>
{% block head %}
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>{% if title is defined %}{{ title }} - {% endif %}{{ siteName }}     </title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="home" href="{{ siteUrl }}">
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/app.css">
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like their ["_head"](https://github.com/duezerouno/0-201/blob/master/templates/_head.twig) template is missing the closing `{% endblock %}` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you need to close the block, easy mistake